# I get an error from R when I run quantmod (getDividens)

Tags: r, quantmod

I've tried to get dividends from R and I get an error.
Here is the codes that I use:

```
library(xts)
library(quantmod)

Tick <- c("A","AA","AADR","AAN","AAP") #have more than 3 thousands symbols.



divs <- xts()
for( sym in Tick) {
  divs <- merge(divs, getDividends(sym, from= "2016-01-04", to="2017-03-09", src="yahoo"))
}
```

The error I have is:

```
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : 
  Handle is already in use elsewhere.
```

I googled about this error, but I couldn't figure out where it came from. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `lapply` :

```
library(quantmod)

result <- Reduce(merge, lapply(Tick, function(x) {
  tryCatch({
    getDividends(x, from= "2016-01-04", to="2017-03-09", src="yahoo")
  }, error = function(e) {}
  )
}))
```

Comment: Hey, I got this error for this time: Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : HTTP error 400.

Comment: Works fine for me though. Can you restart R and try again?

Comment: Could it be because some symbols do not exist in the time period?

Comment: Yes, probably. Try the make this run for small number of symbols which you know exists and see if it works. If that works you probably need to add `tryCatch` to avoid the errors.

Comment: You are right. It works when every symbols are there. Could you let me know how to combine tryCatch with my codes?

Comment: How are you? I experience weird thing with the codes you wrote. Would you mind to see my post that I just uploaded? I've tried to solve this issue all day long, but I still can't figure out.